# Samba able to copy folders but unable to copy files

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, samba

I am currently using CentOS 6.5 and trying to share files over a samba share. On the other machine is Windows 8 x64. I am able to transfer folders from Windows to CentOS over without issues but however, when I try to copy a single file over to CentOS, I get permission denied error on Windows.

Permissions of the folder is as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx.   5 user01 smbusers  4096 Feb 28 23:23 srv
```

And the smb.conf:

```
[srv]
        comment = Data
        path = /srv
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        read only = no
        valid users = @smbusers
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
```

I would like to know what is the problems that is preventing me from copying files over but not folders. Contents inside the folders get copied over without issues. Help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the **owner** of directory/folder where you are going to copy the file in CentOS from Windows, it's usually done by **chown** command. For example if you want to the change the owner of directory named ***share*** from **root** to **your_user_name**, you can do this by following command,

```
sudo chown your_user_name share
```

This will change the owner of **share** folder to your login user.

Comment: you mean the /srv folder? the owner is already user01(which is me) and not root.

Comment: okay, try to change its mode also and give a full read write permission for srv folder, for that you can do it by:                                                                                     "sudo chmod -R 777 srv"